# Equivalent to ArcMap 'viewpoint' in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, imagery

In ArcMap, there is a 'viewpoint' window which allows the user to choose an overlapping image in a mosaic in order to view ground objects at a different angle. ArcGIS Pro does not appear to have this functionality. Is there a new equivalent or is this something that can't be done in ArcGIS Pro?